# How can I implement Amazon EMR to read data from my API calls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

All the examples i've seen are with Java programs?

I want to be able to track the a user's behaviour while navigating my website by looking at all the API calls made by that user. All the API calls are based on data stored in a SQL database.

I also for example want to check all the keywords passed to my search API to have a list of most search terms.

I thought about using Oozie but does anyone have any other suggestions ?

Comment: What do you mean by "API calls made by that user"? Does the user navigate via normal HTTP requests for web pages, or are they calling a backend API service that you provide?

Comment: They are calling a backend API service that I provided. So for example, if they search for "Panda", my API will search the database and return all relevant results.

Comment: Are you logging such requests somewhere, such as raw log files or in a database? Are you also storing all the search requests? Please note that services like EMR need to read the data from somewhere, and your application is responsible for storing that data so that it can be analysed. Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: Im sorry I'm very new to this so I feel overwhelmed. I store all the data in a mySQL database. I understand that EMR has many services, and I thought about using one of those services to batch call the data in my database for further analysis. Which service should I use? Maybe something with flexibility like a noSQL approach.

Answer (score 2):

There are several option for analyzing the data in your database.

**Normal SQL experimentation**

I'd suggest starting with normal SQL statements against your database to experiment with finding what data is of interest. This might be a little slow if you have millions of records, but gives you full flexibility to play around with the data.

**Amazon EMR**

Once you have identified the types of analysis you'd like to run on a regular basis (eg daily or weekly), you could launch an EMR cluster to perform analysis. Please note that this is a powerful but rather complex toolset and the time required to fully utilize it might not be worthwhile.

You can launch a *transient cluster*, which means that the cluster terminates once it has finished the jobs it has been given. Thus, the cluster can be triggered via a scheduled API call and will automatically terminate.

**Amazon Athena**

Amazon Athena provides an SQL interface to data stored in Amazon S3. The common use-case is to analyze log files that are in S3 without having to load them into a database. Athena is powerful and processes data in parallel to give results back very quickly.

**Bottom line:** Start simple. Play with the existing data to figure out what you'd like to discover. Then optimize.

Comment: If I want to create a batch GET request to my API, where can I do that ? And then I'll save the data to my s3, right ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. If you created the API, it is totally under your management.